# ¿Como hago un llamado AJAX con angularjs 1.6 y laravel 5.1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, laravel-5

Estoy intentado hacer una llamada AJAX desde angular 1.6, mi proyecto esta sincronizado con laravel 5.1, tengo conexion a la bd y ya la comprobe, solo necesito descargar los datos y guardarlos en vectores de js, cada columna un vector!!!

Siendo mas claro, estoy integrando laravel 5.1 con angularjs, la integracion esta, y las consultas la bd tambien me funcionan correctamente, lo que necesito es, al seleccionar dos datos (temperatura,precipitacion) o alguno de los dos, y dale clic en un boton aceptar, descargue los datos y me cree un vector con ellos en un servicio de angular... ya tengo vectores en ese servicio, pero fueron datos colocados a mano.

Comment: y el código brother? qué has intentado? si tu pregunta no anda clara para la comunidad de SOes, potencialmente podría ser cerrada. Saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una petición AJAX en AngularJS se hace mediante el servicio [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Su uso es bastante similar a la función ajax de jQuery.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/v1/products'
})
  .then(function ({ data }) {
    // hacer algo con el array de datos
  }, function (response) { // callback de error
    console.error(response.statusText);
  });
```

Ésta función devuelve una [`Promesa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa) por lo que se debe usar `then` para acceder al valor esperado, en éste caso `Response`. El objeto `Response` tiene cinco entradas, entre ellas, `data` que es la que contiene la información enviada por el servidor.